# Invariant cones in Katok-Hasselblatt

Tags: dynamical-systems

I'm having trouble understanding a lemma presented in Katok & Hasselblatt *Introduction to the modern theory of dynamical systems* (p.247). Here's the said lemma :

[image]

I don't understand the second part of the proof. More specifically, how does it come that if $(u,v) \in \tilde{V}^\gamma_p$, then $Df_m(u,v) = (u',v') \in V^\gamma_{f_m(p)}$ ?

By definition, we have that $(u,v) \in (Df_{m-1})_{f_{m-1}^{-1}(p)} V^\gamma_{f_{m-1}^{-1}(p)}$, but I don't see why this implies the conclusion...

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: I get the feeling something's wrong with notations here...